# How to generate xml null values in Oracle?

Tags: xml, plsql

I'm new for `XML` generation through `plsql`.How can generate `XML` using `null` values?
I required below output.

> DealUserDescription  i:nil="true"/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function for creating nil xml element, i'm sure it can be improved:

```
create function add_xml_element(
  p_name in varchar2,
  p_value in varchar2,
  p_namespaces in varchar2 default null,
  p_nil_prefix in varchar2 default null,
  p_nil_namespace in varchar2 default null) return XMLType is

  l_result XMLType;
begin
  if p_value is not null then
    l_result := XMLType('<' || p_name || ' ' || p_namespaces || '>'||p_value||'</' || p_name || '>');
  elsif p_nil_prefix is not null and p_nil_namespace is not null then
    l_result := XMLType('<' || p_name || ' ' || p_namespaces || ' ' || p_nil_namespace || ' ' || p_nil_prefix || ':nil="true"/>');
  else
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Nil prefix or namespace not provided');
  end if;

  return l_result;
end;
```

and plsql script to test it:

```
declare
  l_xml xmlType;

  cursor c_build_xml(cp_value in varchar2) is
    select
      xmlElement("root",
        add_xml_element(
          'node',
          cp_value,
          null,
          'i',
          'xmlns:i="default"'))
    from
      dual;
begin
  open c_build_xml('nodevalue');
  fetch c_build_xml
    into l_xml;
  close c_build_xml;

  dbms_output.put_line(l_xml.getClobVal());

  open c_build_xml(null);
  fetch c_build_xml
    into l_xml;
  close c_build_xml;

  dbms_output.put_line(l_xml.getClobVal());
end;
/
```

script output is as follows:

```
<root>
  <node>nodevalue</node>
</root>

<root>
  <node xmlns:i="default" i:nil="true"/>
</root>
```