# XMLType in oracle not generating tags for columns with Null values

Tags: oracle, plsql, xmltype

I am trying to Convert the below table rows to XMLtype and then to clob

```
ID, PROJ_NO
1   Proj1
2   (null)
3   Proj5
```

I used the below Query to convert each row to xml

```
 select xmltype( cursor(Select * from PROJ_TEST_DEMO where id= 1  )).getclobval() from  dual
```

Result is

```
"<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <PROJ_NO>Proj1</PROJ_NO>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
"
```

While

```
select xmltype( cursor(Select * from PROJ_TEST_DEMO where id=3  ) ).getclobval() from  dual
```

gives

```
"<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <ID>3</ID>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
"
```

Is there a option to stop xmltype from excluding null value columns

Comment: I believe XMLTYPE by itself has no option to do that. Unfortunately, Oracle treatment of nulls is a pain in the ass. Did you check this as workaround  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589876/how-to-generate-xml-null-values-in-oracle

Comment: I don't think that's possible unfortunately. You might need to explicitly name columns and handle the null values yourself or use workaround as mentioned in other comment. Ex. `select XMLType(cursor(select id, nvl(PROJ_NO,'{null}') PROJ_NO from  PROJ_TEST_DEMO where ID = 2)).getclobval() from dual;`

Comment: @KayaNatsumi but the column names needs to be dynamic as we are not aware of the columnnames.. this will be used inside a trigger and we cannot implicitly state column names

Comment: @SreenathGanga, can you provide an example of the trigger ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez Iam trying the compund trigger mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62858490/convert-the-new-row-to-xml-inside-a-oracle-trigger/62861136?noredirect=1#comment111166753_62861136

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dbms_xmlgen with dbms_xmlgen.setNullHandling(qryCtx, dbms_xmlgen.EMPTY_TAG) or dbms_xmlgen.NULL_ATTR:

For example, create own function

```sql
create or replace function f_get_xmltype_with_nulls (cur sys_refcursor, null_handling int default dbms_xmlgen.null_attr)
  return xmltype
as
  /* null_handling may be: 
      DROP_NULLS CONSTANT NUMBER:= 0;  Leaves out the tag for NULL elements.
      NULL_ATTR CONSTANT NUMBER:= 1; (Default) Sets xsi:nil="true".
      EMPTY_TAG CONSTANT NUMBER:= 2; Sets, for example, <foo/>.
  */
  res xmltype;
  lc dbms_xmlgen.ctxhandle;
begin
  lc:=dbms_xmlgen.newcontext(cur);
  -- you can replace null_attr with empty_tag here:
  dbms_xmlgen.setnullhandling(lc, null_handling);
  res:=dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(lc);
  return res;
end;
/
```

then you can use it in queries:

```sql
SQL> select f_get_xmltype_with_nulls(cursor(select null x from dual connect by level<10)) x from dual;

X
------------------------------------------------------------------------
<ROWSET xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <ROW>
  <X xsi:nil = "true"/>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <X xsi:nil = "true"/>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <X xsi:nil = "true"/>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <X xsi:nil = "true"/>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <X xsi:nil = "true"/>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <X xsi:nil = "true"/>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <X xsi:nil = "true"/>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <X xsi:nil = "true"/>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <X xsi:nil = "true"/>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

As you can see second parameter of this function is null_handling:

- DROP_NULLS CONSTANT NUMBER:= 0; Leaves out the tag for NULL elements.
- NULL_ATTR CONSTANT NUMBER:= 1; (Default) Sets xsi:nil="true".
- EMPTY_TAG CONSTANT NUMBER:= 2; Sets, for example, .

Or you can even inline your function into the query:

```sql
with 
   function f_get_xmltype_with_nulls (cur sys_refcursor, null_handling int default dbms_xmlgen.null_attr)
     return xmltype
   as
     /* null_handling may be: 
         DROP_NULLS CONSTANT NUMBER:= 0;  Leaves out the tag for NULL elements.
         NULL_ATTR CONSTANT NUMBER:= 1; (Default) Sets xsi:nil="true".
         EMPTY_TAG CONSTANT NUMBER:= 2; Sets, for example, <foo/>.
     */
     res xmltype;
     lc dbms_xmlgen.ctxhandle;
   begin
     lc:=dbms_xmlgen.newcontext(cur);
     -- you can replace null_attr with empty_tag here:
     dbms_xmlgen.setnullhandling(lc, null_handling);
     res:=dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(lc);
     return res;
   end;
select
   f_get_xmltype_with_nulls(cursor(select null as x from dual)) as xxx 
from dual
/
```

Result with default NULL_ATTR:

```sql
XXX
-----------------------------------------------------------------
<ROWSET xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <ROW>
  <X xsi:nil = "true"/>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

Result with default EMPTY_TAG:

```sql
select
   f_get_xmltype_with_nulls(cursor(select null as x from dual),2) as xxx 
from dual;

XXX
-------------------------------------
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <X/>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

Comment: Iam trying  your suggestion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62858490/convert-the-new-row-to-xml-inside-a-oracle-trigger/62861136?noredirect=1#comment111166753_62861136